# How do I calculate effect size for Anderson-Darling test?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, effect-size, anderson-darling-test

I'm looking at the list of tests and effect sizes on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/statsExpressions/vignettes/stats_details.html, but I can find any way to calculate effect size for Anderson-Darling test. Does effect size exist for AD? How can I calculate it?

Comment: Do you just mean a measure of how different two distributions are?

Comment: The [Anderson-Darling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) is basically a goodness-of-fit test, so it is not testing any underlying *effect*. So it is not clear what an effect size should measure, a numerical measure of distance from closest normal distribution? Or?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorson I want the OP to comment on this, but I took it to mean something like KL divergence of the empirical distribution from the theoretical distribution, and I could be content to call that an effect size for distribution difference.